# Why is Linux so slow on VirtualBox for Windows 10?

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, graphics-card

I need to create a Virtual Machine running a Linux-based OS. I have tried with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS. The problem that I can't help having is that its interface is laggy and slow in terms of its response, and it is obvious that it's due to a low video performance. A simple example: if I play a 720p video on YouTube, Firefox might crash or the image of the video usually stays frozen.

I have done a little research and the problem is, apparently, how the VM virtualises the graphic resources of my computer, since it doesn't have a videocard. However, my host computer with Windows 10 works just fine, without any troubles. I have also installed the VM in another laptop of mine, which counts with a graphic board, and the difference of performance is remarkable, for the better.

*Hardware specs:*

I5-5200 @ 2.20GHz 2.19GHz
8GB RAM (7.88 to be used)
Intel HD Graphics 5500
250GB SSD
Virtualization is on

*Virtual machine specs:*

4000MB RAM (have tried also with 3GB)
128MB for video
3D acceleration enabled
30GB for storage

I have read that common problems are not to have installed VirtualBox Guest Additions or not having enabled Unity 3D, but I have none of them:

[Unity3D is enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzgBb.png)

[VBox Guest Additions is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJo3P.png)

My questions would be:

1. Is there anything that I'm missing or could do in order to improve the performance of the virtual machine?
2. Is there any Linux-based OS which would be more suitable for my computer instead of Ubuntu?

Please, let me know if you need further information. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same CPU in a Lenovo X250, and Linux in VirtualBox is just flat-out slow. Make sure you have Virtualization options enabled in the BIOS.

Comment: I have Windows 10 Pro 16 GB memory here with VMware Workstation 15.5 and two Linux guests running right now:  Ubuntu 18.04 and Kali Linux 2019.4. Both have 2 GB memory assigned to them. Both are running well You have assigned 4 Gb to your guest in an 8 GB host. Try assigning less memory - say 3 GB

Comment: I have updated the post: virtualization is on. I have tried with 3GB as well, but will set it with 2GB just in case. Does your computer have a regular graphic board (not an onboard one like mines)?

Comment: @john, the problem is that I cannot use VMware because it's to be used in a company, and the idea is to use a free solution (VMware has a cost for companies)

Comment: My host machine uses integrated Intel Graphics (high end Intel) which works very well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slow vmware vm with fast brand new laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/793985/slow-vmware-vm-with-fast-brand-new-laptop) VMware supports up to 2GB virtual graphics memory whereas VirtualBox supports up to [256MB virtual graphics memory](https://superuser.com/a/973930/), not 128MB as you reported.

Answer (score -1):

1. Did you try enabling more CPU cores, install add-ons that enable more hardware features?
2. Did you try to limit RAM to what the program needs? (eg: Linux with program only use 1GB of RAM, but 4 GB is allocated? Try 1,5 or 2GB if you're only needing 1GB.
3. Are you running from SSD or hard drive?

That Virtualbox runs slower than native is only normal, as it's not running native.
But the performance penalty I guess should be closer to 5 or 10%, Not 50%.